# how can I get my dto of relations in typeOrm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

**how can I get my dto of relations in typeOrm?**

I have **nationals** and  **provinces**

I use *plainToClass* of *'class-transformer'* and get dto of national

I want get dto of relations ( **provinces** )

```
{
    "code": "Manchester",
    "name": "Manchester",
    "displayOrder": "0",
    "nationalId": 1,
    "national": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "England",
      "code": "England",
      "displayOrder": "1",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-04T07:44:13.186Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-08-04T07:44:13.186Z",
      "version": "0"
    }
},
```

my dto of relations :

```
export class NationalDto {
    name: string;
    code: string;
    displayOrder: number;
}
```

I want get like:

```
{
    "code": "Manchester",
    "name": "Manchester",
    "displayOrder": "0",
    "nationalId": 1,
    "national": {
      "name": "England",
      "code": "England",
      "displayOrder": "1"
    }
},
```

This my code in repository :

```
async findAll(): Promise<Province[]> {
    return await this.find({
        relations : ["nationals"]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both DTOs. For example:

```js
// national dto
export class NationalDto {
    name: string;
    code: string;
    displayOrder: number;
}
```

```js
// provinces dto
export class ProvinceDto {
    name: string;
    code: string;
    displayOrder: number;
    national: NationalDto
}
```

In some cases, you can use nestjs [mapped types](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types) in order to reuse dtos.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

Your DTO that you want to **use in another DTO**.

```js
export class NationalDto {
  name: string;
  code: string;
  displayOrder: number;
}
```

The DTO that **consumes above DTO**

```js
import { Expose, Type } from "class-transformer"
import { NationalDto } from "./NationalDto"

export class ProvinceDto {
  name: string;
  code: string;
  displayOrder: number;
  
  @Type(() => NationalDto)
  @Expose()
  national: NationalDto
}
```